# Python method that returns a float returns different values for the same raw data

Tags: python, django, floating-point

Another Python floating point question. I am creating an application to help our training department. Part of this application is to handle class evaluations. An evaluation consists of a class of equipment, a written test score, an operational test score, and an operational test time. This promises to be long.

There is a formula to calculate the score:

```
score = written_test + operational - best_decimal_time + decimal_time
percentage = score / best score
```

Right now the interface allows for the user to input the test scores and the minutes and seconds for the road test. In theory the score for the best time would be:

```
written_test + operational
```

since the decimal times would offset.

Note that the `written_test` is an attribute of the `student` attribute of an `Evaluation`

Using Django the model definition for an Evaluation is:

```
class Evaluation(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(StudentRegistration)
    machine_class = models.ForeignKey(MachineClass)
    operational = models.IntegerField()
    minutes = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    seconds = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    raw_time = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    decimal_time = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=3, default=0,  null=True, blank=True)
    score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    percent = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    evaluator = models.ForeignKey(Instructor, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

The save method for an evaluation is:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """Sets the raw_time and decimal_time from the minutes and seconds and saves the object."""
    self.raw_time = self.get_raw_time()
    self.decimal_time = self.get_decimal_time()
    self.score = self.get_score()
    super(Evaluation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The get_raw_time method:

```
def get_raw_time(self):
    """Formats the minutes and seconds into a time string d:dd and returns the formatted time."""
    s = '0'
    if self.seconds < 10:
        s = s + str(self.seconds)
    else:
        s = self.seconds
    return '%s:%s' % (self.minutes, s)
```

The get_decimal_time method:

```
def get_decimal_time(self):
    return '%.3f' % ((self.minutes) + (self.seconds / 60.0))
```

The get_best_time method:

```
def get_best_time(self):
    reg_ary = []
    s_class = self.student.scheduled_class_id
    registrations = StudentRegistration.objects.filter(scheduled_class_id=s_class).values('id')
    for r in registrations:
        reg_ary.append(r['id'])
    evaluations = Evaluation.objects.filter(student_id__in=reg_ary).order_by('decimal_time')
    for e in evaluations:
        if e.machine_class == self.machine_class:
            if e.decimal_time < self.get_decimal_time():
                return '%.3f' % round(e.decimal_time, 4)
            else:
                return '%.3f' % round(self.get_decimal_time(), 4)
    return self.get_decimal_time()
```

Finally the get_score method:

```
def get_score(self):
    return '%.2f' % (Decimal(self.student.written_test) + Decimal(self.operational) -
          Decimal(self.get_decimal_time())  + Decimal(self.get_best_time()))
```

Here are the numbers:

```
written_test = 21
operational = 96
minutes = 3
seconds = 1
```

This is the first entry to the table so it is the best time, so when the score is calculated it should be `21 + 96 = 117`.

When I enter those numbers is I get:

```
117 written to the database # correct maybe, I think it should be 117.00 but not huge.
raw_time = 3:01 # correct
decimal_time = 3.017 # correct
best_decimal_time = 3.017 # correct
score = 117.00 # correct
```

When I change the record to 2 seconds I get:

```
116.98 written to the database # incorrect, should still be 117
raw_time = 3:02 # correct
decimal_time = 3.033 # correct
best_decimal_time = 3.033 # correct
score = 117.00 # correct
```

When I delete the record and start again using minute = 3 and seconds = 2 I get :

```
117 written to the database # correct mostly
raw_time = 3:02 # correct
decimal_time = 3.033 # correct
best_decimal_time = 3.033 # correct
score = 117.00 # correct
```

Finally, when I change the record to 1 second I get:

```
117.02 written to the database # incorrect, should still be 117
raw_time = 3:01 # correct
decimal_time = 3.017 # correct
best_decimal_time = 3.017 # correct
score = 117.00 # correct
```

Here is exactly where each of these values come from:

```
I looked in the database for the value written there
raw_time = self.raw_time
decimal_time = self.decimal_time
best_decimal_time = self.get_best_time()
score = self.get_score()
```

I suspect that this is a problem with the binary representation of floats but cannot seem to figure out how to fix it. I have tried casting to Decimal, something is just off somewhere and my brain hurts a little. I know this is long but I wanted to make sure to give as much pertinent information as possible. Could it be that the time is to three digits of precision and the score is not?

The part that is confusing me is that the database is getting the results of `get_score()` for the values that are written to the database, but what is displayed in the interface is different.

Suggestions?

Comment: Difference 0.02 looks too large than it is usual for binary floating point representation problems.

Comment: That is what I thought originally, but I cannot come with a better reason why the `get_score()` method returns two different values on the edit only......Wait, it is just on the edits, so what is causing the problem when the value in the database is changed. Might be onto something.....

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got so caught up in the float thing that I missed the actual problem. The problem is that I need to check if the best time in the database belongs to the current evaluation and if it does then use `self` instead of the database value.

+1 to Messa for getting me thinking.